# Git Subtree when pushed to Bitbucket or Github

Tags: git

I have a question concerning subtrees. I have a project where I use a lib which I have added using the subtree mechanism. Before that I always use submodules which works quite well if you know what you are doing. But I want to try subtrees for a different project.

So subtrees works also very good but my problem is that when I push my repo to github or bitbucket - doesn't matter and someone else clone the repo ...the remote information for the subtree is missing.

So if I have a lot of libs added via subtrees and If i lost my master then I have to add all the remote of the subtrees by hand... or what is the correct workflow here?

I am always wondering how the linux is managed that way because as I know linux is builded from a lot of subtrees.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major shortcoming of Bitbucket  (and I presume github).  The reason why your links are not pushed up to Bitbucket is because the subtree links are stored outside of the repository.

For instance, in Sourcetree, the subtree links are stored in `.git/sourcetreeconfig`

```
<RepositoryCustomSettings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AutoRefresh>true</AutoRefresh>
  <AutoRefreshRemotes>true</AutoRefreshRemotes>
  <DraftCommitMsg />
  <IncomingSavedCount>0</IncomingSavedCount>
  <LastCheckedRemotes>2017-11-29T10:37:38.3041741-05:00</LastCheckedRemotes>
  <LastUsedView>FileStatus</LastUsedView>
  <LogBranchFilterIndex>0</LogBranchFilterIndex>
  <OutgoingSavedCount>0</OutgoingSavedCount>
  <SidebarExpandedItems>
    <string>File Status</string>
    <string>Branches</string>
    <string>Remotes</string>
  </SidebarExpandedItems>
  <SidebarWidth>210</SidebarWidth>
  <SubtreeLinks>
    <SubtreeLink>
      <SourcePathUrl>http://URL_TO_YOUR_BITBUCKET/scm/l20/00-0000-xx-eclipseutils.git</SourcePathUrl>
      <Prefix>00-0000-xx-eclipseutils</Prefix>
      <Refspec>master</Refspec>
    </SubtreeLink>
  </SubtreeLinks>
</RepositoryCustomSettings>
```

However, this file is maintained by the Sourcetree tool and not actually stored in the repository itself.

A potential workaround would be to store the file `.git/sourcetreeconfig` in the repo (e.g. `_sourcetreeconfig`) and copy the file to .git whenever you checkout the repository.

It's really a shame because subtrees really fix a lot of the organizational shortcomings of Bitbucket.